# How to pass value from controller to /resourceModel/Collection.php class

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, admin-controller, ui-grid

There are two table t1 and t2

t1
id, name
1, abc
2, pqr

t2
id, t1_id, phone
1 ,  1   , 7894561230
2, 1 , 7894645125
3, 2, 7445582145

I am having two grids, grid 1 showing the first table. Now if i clicked on 1st item. I should see the second grid with only t1_id == clicked item.

Both are UI grid

When i am clicking on an item it call the controller with parameter id. Now how can i filter the other grid with this id?

Comment: Can you please more elaborate your question with code so we get more idea about it?

Comment: please check i have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution To use session. What i observed was the constructor of the collection was getting called 3 times, this were erassing the data of request params.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you have UI grids, means in the second grid you must have a Dataprovider, you can check there if there is a, id available in the post then you can filter(by using *addFieldToFilter()* ) it according to id or will show all the data. 
And, as you mentioned you have two tables then you can also put a join(by using *getSelect()*...) to fetch data from both the tables.

Comment: Well i don't have dataprovider.